# Plotting data from a Pandas Dataframe with distinct curves based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
City      timestamp HUMI    year
Beijing   10100     43.0    2010
Chengdu   10100     81.2    2010
Beijing   10101     47.0    2010
Chengdu   10101     86.99   2010
Beijing   10102     43.0    2010
Chengdu   10102     86.99   2010
Beijing   10103     55.0    2010
Chengdu   10103     86.89   2010
Beijing   10104     51.0    2010
Chengdu   10104     86.79   2010
Beijing   10105     47.0    2010
Chengdu   10105     93.13   2010
```

I would like to plot HUMI as a function of timestamp, and have a curve per city. Is there a one-line command which would allow me to do this? I have already checked the [Pandas visualization page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) and didn't see it (or miss it).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.pivot('timestamp','City','HUMI').plot()
```

And alternative with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df.set_index(['timestamp','City'])['HUMI'].unstack().plot()
```

[image: graph]

Detail:

```
print (df.pivot('timestamp','City','HUMI'))
City       Beijing  Chengdu
timestamp                  
10100         43.0    81.20
10101         47.0    86.99
10102         43.0    86.99
10103         55.0    86.89
10104         51.0    86.79
10105         47.0    93.13
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I want to continue by splitting the data even more: plot HUMI as function of timestamp and making a curve per City-year combination? Or any number of distinguishing columns?